# Como limpar uma string para o valor anterior depois de usar o strcat()?

Tags: c, string

Eu estou usando a função `strcat()` para concatenar string e estou com dificuldades para retornar a string ao estado anterior, o que eu tentei até agora foi isto, porém com nada de sucesso:

```
const char *get_route(const char *route)
{
    const char *final_str = strcat("https://discord.com/api/v9", route);
    return final_str;
}
```

Eu pego a string que vem no parâmetro `route`, como por exemplo `/users/@me` e concateno com a `discord_api_url`, ficando por exemplo `https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me`, porém quando uso a função de novo, o novo valor que vem de `route` não é concatenado com a variável `discord_api_url` e sim com a anterior que era `https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me`, eu já tentei usar `malloc()` em uma nova string e copiar a `https://discord.com/api/v9` para ela, mas quando eu dou um `free()` a string vai embora :p

Como faço pra depois da concatenação, a string da URL não ser modificada e eu poder reutilizar essa função de novo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eu consegui arranjar a seguinte solução para funcionar como eu queria:

```
char *discord_api_mutable = NULL;

const char *get_route(const char *route)
{
    static const char *discord_api_url = "https://discord.com/api/v9";
    const size_t str_size = strlen(discord_api_url) + strlen(route) + 1;

    if (discord_api_mutable == NULL)
        discord_api_mutable = malloc(str_size);
    else
        discord_api_mutable = realloc(discord_api_mutable, str_size);

    strcpy(discord_api_mutable, discord_api_url);
    strcat(discord_api_mutable, route);

    return discord_api_mutable;
}
```

Não sei se é a correta, mas funciona, se alguém souber uma melhor, ficarei agradecido